# How do I add and remove divs using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code I am working on
**create.blade.php**

I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198719/dynamically-adding-and-removing-div-using-jquery)  and [this tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/02/05/laravel-multiple-images-upload-tutorial/) in order to replicate a `div`. I have managed to clone the `div` and display. My issue comes when I try removing the added `div` as it does not work. How do I go about it? I have added the remove function to my script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function() {
    $("#education-clone").clone().appendTo("#edu");
  });
  $(".remove").click(function() {
    $("#education-clone").remove(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-card" id="education">
  <h5>Education</h5>
  <div id="edu">
    <div class="form-row" id="increment">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>School</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="school[]" placeholder="School/University">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>From</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="school_from[]" placeholder="From">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>To</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="school_to[]" placeholder="To">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Action</label>
        <button class="form-control btn add" type="button">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row" id="education-clone">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>School</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="school[]" placeholder="School/University">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>From</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="school_from[]" placeholder="From">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>To</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="school_to[]" placeholder="To">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label>Action</label>
        <button class="form-control btn-danger remove" type="button">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button class="btn">Next</button>
</div><br>
```

Comment: Can we answer or someone wants to comment - Otherwise i know it will be downvoted ?

Comment: So many issues. 1. delegate 2. IDs need to be unique. 3. relative addressing

Comment: Without giving the clone a class to find it by, you can try `$("#edu").on("click",".remove", function() { $(this).closest("div").closest("div").remove(); });`

Comment: @mplungjan The code works well for removing however after I remove the add button does not work.

Comment: 1. Give the div you want to clone a class of containerDiv and 2. do this

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edu").on("click", ".add", function() {
    $("#education-clone").clone().appendTo("#edu");
  });
  $("#edu").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    if ($("#edu").find("div.containerDiv").length > 1) {
      $(this).parents("div.containerDiv").remove();
    }
  });
});`

Answer (score -2):

> How do I add and remove divs using JQuery?

You won't need the jQuery library for an action as straightforward as this.

In vanilla javascript, to remove a `<div>` such as:

```
<div id="remove-me">...</div>
```

You can use the `.remove()` method:

```
let elementToRemove = document.getElementById('remove-me');
elementToRemove.remove();
```

Comment: 1. jquery.  2.  missing delegation (the reason for the issue) 3. relative addressing is needed

Comment: Your answer is not relevant in any way to the question asked. OP needs something like `$("#edu").on("click",".remove", function() { $(this).closest("div").closest("div").remove(); });`